# Access Update Query Shows Records being updated but doesn't update some

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

Simple update query that has been working for weeks but now seems to update only some of the records.

Both tables have ID's that I use to match between them, I clearly see that the records that need to be updated are there when I look at the query results but when I run the query and look at the table being updated there are some fields not populated. Very strange since they are showing up when I look into the query but then only some are updated in the table.

Here's the query;

```sql
UPDATE [Asset List] 
INNER JOIN [Combine Control] ON [Asset List].ID = [Combine Control].ID 
SET [Asset List].[Completed 2022] = [Combine Control].[Completed];
```

Anything I'm overlooking or if anyone has had this issue before please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `[Combine Control].[]` is not a valid field reference.

Comment: Query as posted could never have worked because of that incomplete field reference. These ID fields are not both autonumber?

Comment: I apologize, I missed adding that. I put that into my question now. That's the query I have/works randomly.